# How does Apache Camel AS2 handle async mdn

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, edi

i have a very simple route as a as2 server:

```
from("as2://server/listen?serverPortNumber=7777&requestUriPattern=/").id("as2Listener").bean(AS2Controller.class);
```

when i receive an async mdn from my partner, I see in the log that the AS2 Server components receive an incoming as2 request and it process the request, but it doesn't get into the process method in my controller class (normal as2 messages from my partner gets process in the process method in the controller class no problem).  Can anyone help with where the mdn message gets processed in the whole flow?

Thanks!

Edit:
Normal AS2 Request can get process fine, but when I receive a MDN message, it doesn't get passed into my controller, instead there is this error before and it quits before passing it over:
[The Error Message I get when I receive a mdn message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5jKw.jpg)

Comment: Hi, I'm currently working on this, I couldn't find any examples, I'm using spring-boot . Do you have anything to share as a starting point? your help is really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing the code on Spring Boot, you can call bean method by "as2controller" (which you give the name) or you can autowire the class and call it directly.

```
@Autowired
AS2Controller as2controller ;

//.bean(as2controller);
```

More info, https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/bean-component.html

Comment: thanks...... but it's not that it can't find my class (because normal as2 requests gets process in my controller class no problem), it's more to the case when i receive a mdn message, it doesn't get called into my class, instead, there's an error before it gets passed to my class: Failed to extract EDI message: invalid content type 'multipart/report' for AS2 request message

Comment: You should try to use onException handling top of the route controller or you can try to use doTry catch mechanism